# How to connect email after Google Sign Up with Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, google-signin, azure-ad-msal

I have a SignIn flow configured on Azure AD B2C for a web application built on Angular that uses msal for setting up config and a backend built on ASP.NET Core API.
I was implementing the Google Sign-Up manually with the following steps:

1. Generating authorization URL on the backend and returning it to the frontend to initiate the Google sign up

   ```
   { "client_id", settings.Value.ClientId },
   { "redirect_uri", oauthRedirectUrl },
   { "response_type", "code" },
   { "scope", "openid email profile" },
   { "access_type", "offline" },
   { "state", state },
   { "prompt", "login" },
   { "nonce", "defaultNonce" },
   { "code_challenge_method", "S256" },
   { "code_challenge", codeChallenge }
   ```
2. After selecting an account and being redirected to the redirect uri, validate state and exchange code for an access token on the backend
3. Getting user profile info from Google /userinfo endpoint.
4. Creating a user account on Azure AD B2C

   ```
   public async Task<string> RegisterExternalUser(
      string email,
      CancellationToken cancellationToken
   )
   {
   var userToCreate = new User
   {
       DisplayName = email,
       Identities =
       [
           new()
           {
               SignInType = "federated",
               Issuer = "google.com",
               IssuerAssignedId = email
           }
       ],
       AccountEnabled = true,
   };

   try
   {
       var user = await graphServiceClient.Users.PostAsync(userToCreate, null, cancellationToken)
           ?? throw new Exception("User not found after registration");
       return user.Id!;
   }
   catch (ODataError exception) when (exception.ResponseStatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
   {
       throw new UserAlreadyRegisteredException(email);
   }
   }
   ```

The problem is the following. I have already a registered user on Azure who registered via emailAddress SignInType. When this user tries to register using a Google account with the same email, another Azure user record appears with another IdpObjectId, which is not what I want. Why do I have two records and not one?
My guess is that it is related to the EmailVerified property being false when trying to get user via /userinfo endpoint on the step 3, but not sure.

Maybe I am doing something wrong or missing some parts, so any suggestions or remarks are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because B2C treats social accounts differently from local accounts.

For social accounts, it creates a "shadow" account.

If you look at the custom policies, local accounts are accessed by "objectId", whereas social accounts are accessed by "alternativeSecurityId".

If you look in the "Users" tab under the "Identities" column, you'll see the sign-in type is "federated", whereas for local, it's "emailAddress" or "username".

If you want both identities in the same user account, you have to [link](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples?tab=readme-ov-file#account-linking) them.